# I want to undo the auto-hide for the taskbar but my windows 10 pro is not activited

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, windows-activation

My Taskbar is in auto hide mode because I downloaded a application to auto hide it when I didn't know what that meant, once I pressed on auto hide and looked at it for some time I didn't want it and the application (smart task on the windows 10 store) didn't let me undo the action. I have deleted the application and my taskbar is still hidden.

This gets really annoying and I try to move the taskbar to different locations to see if it would bother less but they all bother in some way or form.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the taskbar after you pass over it with your mouse and you will get an option to go to taskbar settings (WIN 10). You will see the setting to un hide it.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to do.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StuckRects3]
"Settings"=hex:30,00,00,00,fe,ff,ff,ff,02,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,3e,00,00,00,1e,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,1a,04,00,00,80,07,00,00,38,04,00,00,60,00,00,00,01,00,\
  00,00
```

Save the above code as a text file and rename it to TaskBar.reg, make sure you have enabled `View→File name extensions`, then double click on the file to import the file to registry.

Then it should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > Personalization > Click on Taskbar on the left side, and turn Off "Automatically hide the taskbar in desktop mode" on the right side.